# Scrolling works in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm using the following code to scroll the window when a user clicks on a few different links:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#footerlink").click(function(){
    $("#slide1").slideto({});
});
$("#logo").click(function(){
    $("#slide1").slideto({});
});
$("#home").click(function(){
    $("#slide1").slideto({});
})      
$("#others").click(function(){
    $("#slide2").slideto({});
})
$("#me").click(function(){
    $("#slide3").slideto({});
});
$("#laughs").click(function(){
    $("#slide4").slideto({});
});
})
```

The slide functionality is coming from this script:

```
(function(b) {
b.fn.slideto = function(a) {
    a = b.extend({
        slide_duration: 1000,
        highlight_duration: 3E3,
        highlight: false,
        highlight_color: "#FFFF99"
    }, a);
    return this.each(function() {
        obj = b(this);
        b("body").animate({
            scrollTop: obj.offset().top
        }, a.slide_duration, function() {
            a.highlight && b.ui.version && obj.effect("highlight", {
                color: a.highlight_color
            }, a.highlight_duration)
        })
    })
}
})(jQuery);
```

My problem is the scrolling only works in Chrome and not Firefox or IE. FF and IE degrade nicely so the links still work, but I really like the scrolling animation.

FYI:  I am calling Jquery with these two lines:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a Fiddle of my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/LwXR3/

Can you help me track down my issue?

Comment: This isn't a solution, but to get rid of that flicker that occurs immediately after clicking, your event handlers should kill the event.

Comment: Hi MicronXD, I'm so new to Javascript that I'm not actually sure how to do that.

Comment: updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LwXR3/11

Comment: If you declare the first parameter of your event handler, you'll have a handle on the event object in your function. In this case, we're telling the browser not to do what it was gonna do (jump down the anchor whose name is in the clicked-link's href).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is too long to be in a comment. You should really avoid the copy paste mess in that code above. The code is almost exactly the same minus the ids. Use the href to get the location instead of hard coding it.

**HTML**

```
<a class="slideLinks" href="#foo">go to foo</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".slideLinks").on("click", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); //p[revent the click
    $(this.hash).slideto({}); //call your slide to function with the hash value for the id
});
```

Comment: So with this, I would be able to simply add the class "slideLinks" to any link and it would invoke the slide?

Comment: Any link that has a hash. Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I can get it to work in fiddle, but live is another matter.  I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious.   Live Example - http://joeymadethis.com/joeymcdaniel/     Note: Only the "Home" link uses the new slideLinks class.

Comment: Thank you @epascarello!  My mistake was not in formatting my external js file correctly.  Duh.  I'm using the update code you suggested and the scrolling now works in all modern browsers!  Awesome!